# OWIN with Identity 2 - avoid regularly hitting the database for common objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have just taken the plunge and started to learn the OWIN style of authorizing users into MVC applications. One issue I'm having is storing objects since the move away from session objects and into claims.

Traditionally what I would do is authenticate the user, and then store the User object in the session. This is useful when you are regularly using the data from that object all over the application.

Now that I have moved to OWIN with Identity, I instead store the UserId as a claim. I understand that the use of complex objects is best avoided with claims.

So I find that I'm regularly having to hit the database to read User information based on the UserId.

Here is how I am reading the UserId claim:

```
List<Claim> claims = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims.ToList();
var ret = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == StaffClaims.OrganisationId);
```

Is there a way that I can avoid taking this ID and reading the corresponding record from the DB each time? I want to achieve something like having the User object stored in memory somewhere.

Alternatively, does Entity Framework 6 allow caching so that I don't hit the database when repeating the same query (unless I know it has changed and should be re-read)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, storing the user object in the session is a hugely bad idea. Don't do that ever.

Second, you don't need to store the user id in a claim; you can get it anytime with `User.Identity.GetUserId()`.

Third, Entity Framework does utilize caching, but not in a way I'd consider it as something you could rely on. If you want to cache something, then do it explicitly with `System.Runtime.Caching`. You can also utilize the `OutputCache` attribute on actions to cache the rendered view, which has the side effect of not requiring database calls to render it again.

Finally, this is not a big deal in the first place. Just fetch the user when you need it. Before you worry about this one simple query, there's probably 10,000 other areas of your application and could and should be optimized first.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you explain why it's a bad idea to store the User object in the session? All other points are well explained.

Comment: @LaurenceFrost Security is one reason. For example Elmah (error capturing component) grabs all the data from session when records errors, including user object. And this data is later stored on a disk for review. This can get into wrong hands.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look into ELMAH too since I have not looked at that before.